# Spring AMQP Template

Tags: spring, spring-rabbit

Please help me. Is instance of `AmqpTemplate` class from RabbitMQ (implementation of AMQP protocol) thread safe. Can it be accessed from multiple threads? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is thread-safe and can be accessed by multiple threads.